# PowerShell script to keep latest 10 images on azure container registry and remaining need to delete

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need a PowerShell script, always keep latest 10 docker image tags in azure container registry and other images need to delete automatically. This script I need to pass via azure pipeline task like AZ CLI inline script. Can any one help me out this.
[image]
I need to keep latest 10 docker images

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please try it by yourself first and come up with specific question of your approach if you have one.

Comment: I have tried something, but it's not working.

Comment: Please share your script here.

Comment: This script I tried over the azure pipeline
$acrName = 'YourACRName'

$repo = az acr repository list --name $acrName
$repo | Convertfrom-json | Foreach-Object {
    $imageName = $_
    (az acr repository show-tags -n $acrName --repository $_ | 
        convertfrom-json )| Select-Object -SkipLast 2 | Foreach-Object {
        az acr repository delete --yes -n $acrName --image "$imageName:$_"
        }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by using the docker and pushed the 12 images to Azure container Registry and used the below PowerShell cmdlet to keep the latest 5 images in the ACR and deleted the other images successfully as shown in the below screenshots.

You can use the below azure purge cmdlet to delete the images based on your requirement i.e., 10/15 days ago.

Here i have taken 0(zero) days ago images to be deleted and the latest 5 images to be kept.

```
az acr run --cmd "acr purge --filter 'hello-world:.*' --ago 0d  --keep 5" --registry testdockeracrcontainer /dev/null
```

**Output after pushing the 12 images to ACR from local**:
[image]

**Output after executing the above PowerShell cmdlet**:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I ran the above command over the pipeline and i'm getting error
az acr run --cmd "acr purge --filter 'testacrpp.azurecr.io/testacrwcu:.*' --ago 1d  --keep 8" --registry TestAcrpp/dev/null
ERROR: the following arguments are required: <SOURCE_LOCATION>

Examples from AI knowledge base:
az acr run --registry MyRegistry --cmd '$Registry/myimage' /dev/null
Queue a run to execute a container command.

az acr run --registry MyRegistry --file hello-world.yaml https://github.com/Azure-Samples/acr-tasks.git
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1

Comment: while running the above cmd in powershell, you have to pass only the repository name after `--filter` and pass only the name of Azure container registry after the `--registry` as shown in the above answer.